# Symfony | Form | Mail

Tags: php, symfony, email, controller

I've got problem with Symfony and I hope you would help me :) 
I created a Form, which takes data from user (email, name, message) and then it saves data in database. Everything works fine but i also want to send e-mail with this data. 
I want to use mail function `mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);`.

My Controller class looks like:

```
public function ContactFormAction(Request $request){
   $post = new ContactForm();
   $form = $this->createFormBuilder($post)
               ->setMethod('POST')
               ->add('email','text',['label' => 'Adres e-mail'])
               ->add('name','text', ['label' => 'Imię'])
               ->add('message','text', ['label' => 'Wiadomość'])
               ->add('save','submit', ['label' => 'Wyślij'])
               ->getForm();



   $form->handleRequest($request);
       if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
       $post = $form->getData();
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $em->persist($post);
       $em->flush();
       $message=''; //thats my problem
       mail('example@example.pl', 'Subject', $message);

       return $this->redirectToRoute('onas');
     }

  return $this->render('default/aboutus.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
 }
```

**My Problem is: how should the $message variable looks like if I want to get this data from user (from a form on my webpage).**

Thanks a lot for all your answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I follow, but, you want to send plain text using user's input just do `$message = $post->getMessage();` and pass it on to `mail`. Is that the issue?

E-mail are, by default, sent in `text/plain` encoding, so you won't be able to use `HTML`. Personally, I prefer to format it a little better than old-plain-text. To achieve this, I usually create a `Twig` template, pass the input data to it and render what I need. That template could contain some HTML which could enhance the email's visual look.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :) Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @WojciechNowaczyk glad I could help :-)